# How to crawl multiple websites and create a text file with the plain text

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I started a new project and I'm new using python scrapy.
I'm trying to craw through multiple websites and get the plain text from them. After that I would like to create a text-file with the raw text.

This is the code that I have. Maybe you can help me and give me some tips on how e.g. I can read other links from the same website.

```
import scrapy


class ForenSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "foren"

    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org", "pijamassurf.com", "indeed.com"]
    start_urls = [
         "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/",
         "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python"]

    def parse(self, response):

        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        data = hxs.select('//body//text()').extract()

        with open('data', 'rw+') as f:
            for item in data:
                f.writelines(str(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

I used **BeautifulSoup** to get the parsedHtml and this is how i retrieved html links from the current html page.

```
parsedHtml = BeautifulSoup(htmlSource, "lxml")
for href in parsedHtml.find_all('a'):
    linkedUrl = href.get('href')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just consider extending one later examples from the [same page](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#following-links). For example:

```
import scrapy

class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
    start_urls = [ "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/", ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for href in response.css("ul.directory.dir-col > li > a::attr('href')"):
            url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_dir_contents)

    def parse_dir_contents(self, response):
        yield  {
            "link": response.url,
            "body": " ".join(filter(None, map(unicode.strip, response.xpath('//body//text()').extract()))),
            "links": response.css("a::attr('href')").extract()
        }
```

Note that this will be less resource intensive than opening and closing a file for each item as you do now. I'm not sure they really mean it as anything more than a debugging step to get started on the tutorial.

Comment: Sorry, since I'm really new in this topic. I have to ask you, how do you generate the text file with the data after using the "yield".

Comment: I already used: scrapy crawl dmoz -o items.json. I get an empty file. The item.py already exists.

Comment: If you're getting empty output file with the `-o`, it's not `yield`'s error but somethign going wrong with the secondary requests. Maybe `url = response.urljoin(href.extract_first())` ?

Comment: No, It is still not working. I get the file and one  [

Comment: Check the logs... Does it crawl multiple URLs or just the initial one?

Comment: I was trying only with one URL with the code you posted. The program doesn't generate the file properly. Maybe I missed something or I'm doing something wrong.